# BSC Wallet hacked. Sweeper in my wallet

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain, bscscan, sweeping

new here!

Recently my seeds were compromised/stolen (maybe a suspicious download). I have some blocked tokens linked to my wallet. Whenever I transfer some Token, the sweeper transfers it to the hacker wallet. The value of locked tokens is more than 5k USD. I would like to know what can I do. This is not a contract but a sweeper.

Thank you all for help.

Comment: There are some services that provide recovery of funds from compromised wallets. Just be aware that those services work similar to the sweeper bots so they don't having a 100% guarantee is misleading.

Comment: Can you recommend the services to me? whitehat on flashbots discord?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used one.